# String query = "SELECT sum(Cardhundred)FROM Dialog";

Tags: java, database

Currently trying to get sum of the **integers** of a column called `Cardhundred`, I does not proceed the answer, can somebody suggest me an idea to get the total of all integers in my column?

I want to get the sum from a column in access database, the column from which I want to get the sum, has all integers value not double or float, and I have done some code for that which gives me no result, it means the text field which supposed to display the result is empty.

This is my code:

```
if(showtotal.isSelected()) { 
   try { 
       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://E:\\Mydb.accdb"); 
       Statement st = conn.createStatement(); 
       String query = "SELECT sum(Cardhundred)FROM Dialog"; 
       ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query); 
       if(rs.next()) { 
           String total=rs.getString("sum(Cardhundred)"); 
           showdate.setText(""+total+""); 
       } 
   } catch(Exception e){ } 
}
```

Comment: Please include the rest of your code and explain what results you are getting. And consider retagging your question as it has nothing to do with Swing.

Comment: 1) Tip: Add @DavidWinder (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) Code is hard to read in comments, best to [edit] the question to add the code, and when that occurs.. 3) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 4) `catch(Exception e){ }` Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this: use the column index (rather than the name) then you don't need to worry about the name of the expression:

```
int total = rs.getInt(1);
```

The column numbering in JDBC starts with 1, not with 0 as with arrays in Java.

Alternatively, use a column alias in your query:

```
String query = "SELECT sum(Cardhundred) as total_number FROM Dialog";
```

Then use that alias to get the value:

```
int total = rs.getInt("total_number");
```

Comment: Actually still its not giving me the result even I used the way that you have mentioned, do you have team viewer software if you can please,

Comment: @SiyamSlk: so what is the error you get? Did you follow the advice in the comments and **print** any exception instead of ignoring it?

Comment: Thank you so much! I got the result